# How can I spend my paper wallet directly?

Tags: raw-transaction, paper-wallet, wallet-import

I am totally new to Bitcoin. Can you tell step by step, how I can spend a paper wallet directly? Or is it necessary to create a software wallet?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you plan on doing ECC math and hashing algorithms by hand (it would take you about a day just to do a single round of SHA256) and publishing the raw binary transaction via raw network protocol, you're going to need some software.

I would recommend getting [Mycelium](https://mycelium.com/), which has a paper wallet import feature. You can then spend it where you like using the wallet.